# Connecting a second server to windows server 2012 essentials

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-essentials

What's the best way to connect a second server to an existing windows server essentials 2012 domain?

I tried the //xyz/connector/ method but I wasn't sure whether I should be supplying the domain administrator user account details, my own standard account details or a new account just for this server.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "//xyz/connector/ method". Also please define what the "best way" would constitute for you?

Comment: Is the connector client supported on a server OS? It looks to me like only Windows 7, 8 and Mac clients are supported.